# Error al agregar header con / en objeto HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core

Estoy tratando de realizar una peticion HTTP POST, estoy teniendo problemas el querer agregar en el header un authorization que tiene caracteres especiales como el / y el =

El codigo que utilizo es le siguiente

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);

foreach (var h in headers)
        {
             request.Headers.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
        }
```

Y la exception que obtengo

**The format of value 'kAw4dhLDTHY8HvEZWZmv7k6/PHw=' is invalid."**

**StackTrace "   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(HeaderDescriptor descriptor, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(HeaderDescriptor descriptor, String value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)\r\n**

Probe varias maneras pero no encontre solucion

Espero puedan ayudarme

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Comment: Seria bueno si puedes copiar todo el codigo que utilizas para "generar la llamada POST". Asi podremos ayudarte mejor. Ya que los encabezados generalmente se los define en la instancia de HttpClient que utilizas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final para resolverlo tuve que que cambiar de metodo al siguiente

```
if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var h in headers)
            {                     
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(h.Key, h.Value);
            }
        }
```

El metodo Headers.Add no se que tipo de validacion realiza que no me dejaba ingresar cierto tipo de caracteres

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente los caracteres que mencionas que dan error, no debería dar. Son caractares permitidos para un encabezado HTTP (en el ejemplo mas abajo lo realizo con el mismo valor que indicas que da error)

Si bien seria bueno que puedas colocar parte del código, para ver como vas armando los encabezados y ayudarte mejor.

Envio de ayuda dos formas de "Enviar" o "setear" encabezados HTTP al realizar un request con HTTPClient en el metodo POST. (Aqui utilizo [HttpClientFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0))

Las dos opciones son:

- OPCION 1: Utilizando el metodo Post (o PostAsync)
- OPCION 2: Utilizando el metodo [Send (o SendAsync)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-6.0) armando un Http (tu ejemplo Parece que utilizas este metodo) con el objeto [HttpRequestMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0)

**OPCION 1: Utilizando el metodo Post (o PostAsync)**

Aqui los encabezados se colocan en objeto HttpClient (porque seria bueno incluso que estos de encabzados de Auth (Authorization) sea configurados a nivel global (para no estar repitiendo en cada request o metodo). Esto tambien se puede hacer.  Aqui dejo un ejemplo de como "armar" y setear httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization con [System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-6.0) donde esta con el msmo

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Jedi>> SearchAsync(JediFilter jediFilter, 
                                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAddress;

        //Add Custom Hader
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
              .Add("X-CustomHeader-1", "kAw4dhLDTHY8HvEZWZmv7k6/PHw=");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
              .Add("X-CustomHeader-2", "0123456789-abcdefghijklmnoprrstuvwxyz");


        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                                scheme: "Basic",
                                parameter: "kAw4dhLDTHY8HvEZWZmv7k6/PHw=");


        var dataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jediFilter);
        
        var data = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(API_JEDI_SEARCH_URL,
                                                            data,
                                                            cancellationToken);

        
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Jedi>>(stream);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

**OPCION 2: Utilizando el metodo [Send (o SendAsync)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-6.0) armando un Http (tu ejemplo Parece que utilizas este metodo) con el objeto [HttpRequestMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0)**

Aquí se utiliza el objeto [HttpRequestMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0) para armar el post y enviar mediante

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Jedi>> SearchUseSendAsync(JediFilter jediFilter,
                                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAddress;


        var dataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jediFilter);

        var data = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);


        var requestUri = new Uri(string.Concat(DEFAULT_BASEADDRESS, API_JEDI_SEARCH_URL));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
                                             requestUri: requestUri)
        { 
            Content = data
        };

        //Add Custom Hader
        request.Headers
              .Add("X-CustomHeader-1", "kAw4dhLDTHY8HvEZWZmv7k6/PHw=");

        request.Headers
              .Add("X-CustomHeader-2", "0123456789-abcdefghijklmnoprrstuvwxyz");


        request.Headers.Authorization = 
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                                scheme:"Basic", 
                                parameter: "kAw4dhLDTHY8HvEZWZmv7k6/PHw=");

        var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,
                                                            cancellationToken);




        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Jedi>>(stream);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Realización de solicitudes HTTP mediante IHttpClientFactory en ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-6.0)
- 

Todos los ejemplos se basan que ejemplo que tenia con llamada POST, y agregue encabezados de ejemplo

- https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/blob/main/009-post-from-csharp/Starwars.Core.ServiceClient/StarwarsServiceClient.cs

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Jose, todo eso que estas comentando lo tenia hecho, el problema es que el metodo .Headers.Add realiza algunas validaciones y no me permite ingresar ese tipo de caracteres, finalmente lo resolvi usando Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(). Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Una consulta ya que estuve revisando tu codigo... te funciono la opcion dos?, ya que veo que estas utilizando la misma clase HttpRequestMessage y el Headers.Add e ingresando los mismos caracteres con los cuales tenia problemas

Comment: Si funciono! [Mira tambien el test](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/blob/a6524d6688bb3240db14986f62a83b985cb4857c/009-post-from-csharp/Starwars.Core.ServiceClient.Tests/StarwarsServiceClientTest.cs#L80) que esta en ese mismo proyecto. No vi las validaciones de Headers? donde dice que valida?