# Uso incorrecto de encabezados HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, http, asp, http-post

Recientemente me encuentro trabajando en la integración de un api de MSM masiva con un portal hecho en .NET, empleando HttpRequestMessage, pero al ejecutar me encuentro con este error

> Uso incorrecto del nombre de encabezado. Asegúrese de que los encabezados de solicitud se usen con objetos HttpRequestMessage, los encabezados de respuesta con objetos HttpResponseMessage y los encabezados de contenido con objetos HttpContent.

Cuento con un método asíncrono y el objetivo es poder enviar n mensajes al dar clic en un botón.

```
public async Task EnviarMasivos()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://holamundo.com/api/"),
                Headers =
                    {
                        { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                        { "account", "123" },
                        { "apiKey", "123" },
                        { "token", "123" },
                    },
                Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"flash\": 0,\n  \"sc\": \"890202\",\n  \"request_dlvr_rcpt\": 0,\n  \"sendDate\": \"1599158819\",\n  \"bulk\": [\n    {\n      \"numero\": \"57123123123\",\n      \"sms\": \"SMS de prueba\"\n    }\n  ]\n}")
                {
                    Headers =
                    {
                        ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
                    }
                }
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(body);
            }          
        }
```

Cuento ademas con un evento desde donde llamo el metodo

```
 protected async void ButtonSendMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await EnviarMasivos();
        }
```

Es importante mencionar que desde el form.aspx tengo establecido la propiedad `Async="true"`, he verificado la estructura y veo todo bien, no se en que estoy fallando. Para ser exactos la ejecucion falla en la linea 4. `var request = new HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: HAce un par de dias una pregunta similar que te puede servir de ayuda o guía [Error al agregar header con / en objeto HttpRequestMessage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536022/error-al-agregar-header-con-en-objeto-httprequestmessage). Dale una mirada. Lo que si voy a probar de generar de "una sola vez" todo el HttpRequestMessage (porque si miras en ese respuesta del post que envio, veras que va por parte con los encabezados y Content

Answer (score 0):

El error te arroja. orque estas tratando de enviar dos veces un encabezado HTTP , que es "Content-Type" (y solo deberia ir en Content)

Mira, prueba comentando el Header que agregas aqui

```
{ "Content-Type", "application/json" }
```

En tu creacion de HttpRequestMessage quedaría

```
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://holamundo.com/api/"),
            Headers =
                {
                    //{ "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                    { "account", "123" },
                    { "apiKey", "123" },
                    { "token", "123" },
                },
            Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"flash\": 0,\n  \"sc\": \"890202\",\n  \"request_dlvr_rcpt\": 0,\n  \"sendDate\": \"1599158819\",\n  \"bulk\": [\n    {\n      \"numero\": \"57123123123\",\n      \"sms\": \"SMS de prueba\"\n    }\n  ]\n}")
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
                }
            }
        };
```

Otra forma de crear el Content es con su constructor, pero va a a modo de comentario

```
Content = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía